# fabricjs delete backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to delete the backgroundImage in a `fabric.Canvas` after setting with:

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('img_url',function() { 
    canvas.renderAll();
```

Or just go back to the standard background? To set the `backgroundColor` to `white` isn't working.

Thanks for helping!
Greetings Max

Comment: Just set it to an empty string — `canvas.setBackgroundImage('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))` (2nd argument here is a callback, to re-render canvas after background image is removed)

Answer (score 12):

This is a snippet from `renderAll` function of `fabric.Canvas`;

```
...
if (this.backgroundColor) {
    canvasToDrawOn.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
    canvasToDrawOn.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
}

if (typeof this.backgroundImage === 'object') {
    this._drawBackroundImage(canvasToDrawOn);
}
...
```

Clearly, the background color is, in fact, being set to white when you do `canvas.backgroundColor = white;`. But, since `canvas.backgroundImage` is still an `Image` object, it is drawn over whatever color you fill the background with.

So, when you don't want the `backgroundImage` to be drawn, you need to set it to `0`. It doesn't work with `null`, since `typeof this.backgroundImage === 'object'` still evaluates to `true` in `renderAll`, prompting `backgroundImage` to be drawn. It works with `canvas.backgroundImage = 0;`, though.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EQEBT/)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is also working: 

    canvas.backgroundImage = false;

Comment: @droiddude Of course it does. As long as `typeof this.backgroundImage === 'object'` evaluates to `false`, `backgroundImage` will not be drawn. Why, `canvas.backgroundImage = 'I\'m seriously an image!'` works. http://jsfiddle.net/sau4M/

Answer (score 5):

Set the background image to `null` will remove it.

```js
canvas.setBackgroundImage(null, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

You can also write a function like this to clear both the background image and background color which is handy.

```js
function clearCanvasBackground() {
  if (canvas) {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(null);
    canvas.setBackgroundColor('');
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi my **FabricJs** version is **4.5.1**

Both Solutions do not work for me. Because I am using **FabricJs** in angular with fabric types.

I have found a solution when I have check FabricJs source code.

We can simply

> setBackgroundImage

with an empty

> Fabric.Image Object.

This way we can achieve **delete Background image** Functionality.

Here is the code snippet which can be used for this solution.

```
const image = new fabric.Image('');
canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```