# Background color is set back of background image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I want to set background color when color is selected. The background color gets selected and is also shown but if i select the image and then the background color, then the background color is always behind image. If i select the text, the text is shown on top of the background. How can i do similar to background color? I mean when background color is set, the color should be shown like second screenshot. 
[image]

[image]

Here is my code to set background image and color

```
componentDidMount() {
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.canvasEl);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleDeleteKey, false);
  canvas.on("object:selected", e => this.setState({ selected: e.target }));
  canvas.on("selection:cleared", e => this.setState({ selected: undefined }));
  this.setState({ canvas: canvas });
  this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage, canvas);
}


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.getSelectedColor.hex) {
    this.setCanvasBackgroundColor(
      nextProps.getSelectedColor.hex,
      this.state.canvas
    );
  }
  if (nextProps.getSelectedImage.selectedImage) {
    this.setCanvasBackground(
      nextProps.getSelectedImage.selectedImage,
      this.state.canvas
    );
  }
}

setCanvasBackground = (image, canvas) => {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, e => {
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
};

setCanvasBackgroundColor = (color, canvas) => {
  const rgbColor = new fabric.Color(color).toRgb();
  canvas.setBackgroundColor(rgbColor.toString(), () => canvas.renderAll());
};
```

Comment: Have you tried forcing image removal on background colour select?

Comment: @Pyromonk I tried this.state.canvas.backgroundImage = null; but did not work

Comment: When image is selected, the image is shown top of the background color which is expected one but while background image is in canvas, if i select for color to show up in the canvas, the background color is not shown on top of the background image. When color is selected, i dont want the first screenshot type but i am expecting to have second screenshot type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fabricjs delete backgroundImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171378/fabricjs-delete-backgroundimage)

Comment: @Pyromonk that mean i have to use `canvasToDrawOn` inside `nextProps.getSelectedColor.hex` in `componentWillReceiveProps.`

Comment: `this.state.canvas.backgroundImage = 0` instead of `this.state.canvas.backgroundImage = null` should remove the background image.

Comment: Tried that too but did not work.